# setx in Windows 10 removes backslashes

Tags: windows, setx

I'm trying to set my HOME path in Windows 10:

```
setx -m HOME C:\Users\MyName
```

Then I check the variable's value:

```
echo %HOME%
```

and it returns

```
c:UsersMyName
```

This is a pain, since I'm trying to use Git with ssh and it needs to know the home folder where my .ssh folder is stored. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `setx -m HOME %USERPROFILE%` work? or `setx -m HOME "C:\Users\MyName"`

Comment: if you need to use `setx` then probably you're doing it wrong. `setx` is used to set a variable permanently so it should be done once only, and can be replaced by other methods like editing the registry. Besides you don't need `%HOME%` because there's already `%USERPROFILE%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're calling `setx` from `bash`. Since `\` is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in bash and most other Unix shells, it won't result in a literal backslash. You need to escape the backslash itself with `\` or quote it with `'`:

```
$ echo setx -m HOME C:\Users\MyName
setx -m HOME C:UsersMyName
$ echo setx -m HOME 'C:\Users\MyName'
setx -m HOME C:\Users\MyName
$ echo setx -m HOME C:\\Users\\MyName
setx -m HOME C:\Users\MyName
```

Or just call `setx` from a Windows shell like cmd or powershell. But as I said, if you need to call `setx` from a script every time you run it then you're doing it wrong. In that case you need to use a normal `set`:

```
set "HOME=%USERPROFILE%"
```